# Derived classes of abstract class in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, abstract-class, derived-class

Good day everyone.

I have a question about making and using derived classes of some base abstract class.

I can't quite understand how it works.

My goal: Make a basic class that will define what functions there should be, and then create different derived classes. Then to make an array of base class and instantiate in it different derived classes.

For example:

```
abstract class UIElement
{
    //constructor
    abstract public UIElement();
    //draw element
    abstract public void Draw(int mouseX, int mouseY);
    //checks if the element is pointed at by mouse
    abstract public Boolean IsPointed(int mouseX, int mouseY);
    //defines what happens when clicked
    abstract public void Click(int mouseX, int mouseY);
    //destructor
    abstract public ~UIElement();
}
```

Then create several derived classes and do like that:

```
UIElement[] qwe = new UIElement[3];
qwe[0] = new UIElementButton();
qwe[1] = new UIElementLabel();
qwe[2] = new UIElementSomethingElse();
```

1) What is the proper way to do it, because I can't find a definitive answer or an article that would explain it...

2) About class variables, where they should be declared: base class or derived?

3) What if different derived classes have different variables, how that should be addressed?

4) Can derived classes have different constructor including different arguments?

Comment: Not really clear, but what you are doing in indeed correct.

Comment: And what's wrong with that? Your code seems correct. The only thing I would point out is there will hardly be any use for the abstract destructor. You should rather implement `IDisposable` instead.

Comment: @kkm, it doesn't work never the less :)

Comment: Your question is everything but clear. Try to describe what precisely your problem is.

Comment: @NewProger, how exactly does it not work? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception? What is the error message?

Comment: @Ondrej_Tucny, can you please provide an exaple on how I can do that?

Comment: @NewProger, constructors and finalizers (or "destructors") can't be abstract. And a finalizer can't be public

Comment: @Daniel_Hilgarth my question was: how to properly do what I described. Because I only got overal concept, but not the details of implementation. But now it is answered, so it's all good :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In comments below, questionner is looking for advice on best practices for writing inheritence hierachies with abstract classes

From a general best-practices and correctness point of view, you ought to declare your UIElement base class without abstract on the constructor and without a finalizer. e.g.

```
public abstract class UIElement
{
    //constructor
    protected UIElement();
    //draw element
    public abstract void Draw(int mouseX, int mouseY);
    //checks if the element is pointed at by mouse
    public abstract bool IsPointed(int mouseX, int mouseY);
    //defines what happens when clicked
    public abstract void Click(int mouseX, int mouseY);
}
```

You could then implement derived classes as follows

```
public class UIElementButton : UIElement
{
    // Optional - create parameterless constructor and
    // explicitly call base constructor
    public UIElementButton() : base()
    {
    } 

    // Mandatory - must override abstract methods
    public override Draw(int mouseX, int mouseY)
    {
    }

    // Mandatory - must override abstract methods
    public override Boolean IsPointed(int mouseX, int mouseY)
    {
    }

    // Mandatory - must override abstract methods
    public override void Click(int mouseX, int mouseY)
    {
    }
}
```

You are correct that if you define derived classes as per the above, you could instantiate elements and store in an array of the base type as follows:

```
UIElement[] qwe = new UIElement[3]; 
qwe[0] = new UIElementButton(); 
qwe[1] = new UIElementLabel(); 
qwe[2] = new UIElementSomethingElse(); 

qwe[0].Click(1, 2); // Invokes UIElementButton.Click
qwe[1].Draw(3, 4);  // Invokes UIElementLabel.Draw
```

You should also be aware there is a UIElement class defined in WPF. This won't be a problem if you define a namespace for your type, but perhaps consider a more explicit type name such as `BaseElement` to distinguish your custom type.

---

**Regarding your queries in comments:**

For further advice on usage of abstract classes, please see [All about abstract classes - Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6118/All-about-abstract-classes).  - Where should class variables be declared: base class or derived? 
 - What if different derived classes have different variables, how that should be addressed? 
 - Can derived classes have different constructor including different arguments?

These are really the topic for different questions or own research on google, however as a starter I can say:

1. Class variables should be declared in the scope where they are needed. Meaning if you have a variable `Guid _uiElementId` and want it to be accessed by derived types, it should be declared in the base class and marked as `protected`. If you have a variable in UIElementButton called `Point _mousePoint` and only UIElement button needs it, leave it in there and mark as `private`
2. That's fine - any type can see its own private variables and protected variables from base classes. Just make sure names don't clash
3. Yes they can, for instance.

---

```
 public class UIElementButton : UIElement    
 {    
    private string _buttonText; 

    // Overloaded ctor
    public UIElementButton(string buttonText) : base()
    {
        buttonText = buttonText;
    } 

    // Default constructor. Mark as private or protected 
    // to hide from external API
    public UIElementButton() : base()
    {
    } 
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. It seems I missed few points when I tried to learn how it works. Thanks to your answer it seems now I understand it :) I will try to implement in now.

Comment: @NewProger glad I could be of help. For future reference please try to explain the question more clearly as I had to guess what you really needed. Fortunately I made a lucky guess! Is there anything else I can help with? Post in comments. Regards

Comment: If possible can you please include in your answer information about class variables, where they should be declared: base class or derived? And what if different derived classes have different variables, how that should be addressed?
And second question can derived classes have different constructor including different arguments?
Sorry to take your time on that... but I will make sure to at least choose your answer and "up" it.

Comment: @NewProger I suggest you update your question to ask these things. Also a more general Q - you are asking about how to write an inheritence hierarchy using abstract classes in c#.

Comment: @NewProger yes better - the clearer and more consise you are the more likely to get a good answer

Comment: I don't know how to thank you :) You went our of your way to answer all the questions in depth! Now it all clear to me and I'm already implementing it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

If I guess correctly, the OP comes from a C++ background. There are lots of parallels between C++ and C#, but not all features match 1:1.

If you want your "base class" to just set-up the valid operations for all descendants, i.e. it has no code, you should use an interface:

```
public interface IUIElement
{
  //draw element
  void Draw(int mouseX, int mouseY);
  //checks if the element is pointed at by mouse
  bool IsPointed(int mouseX, int mouseY);
  //defines what happens when clicked
  void Click(int mouseX, int mouseY);
}
```

There's no need for a constructor or a destructor, or to explicitly declare the methods as public, because an interface cannot contain private methods/properties, that is deferred to the classes that implement it.

After this, you can declare your classes like (Visual Studio can stub them for you):

```
public class UIElementButton : IUIElement
{
  public UIElementButton()
  {
     ...
  }

  void Draw(int mouseX, int mouseY)
  {
     ...
  }

  bool IsPointed(int mouseX, int mouseY)
  {
     ...
  }

  void Click(int mouseX, int mouseY)
  {
  }
}
```

The rest of your code (with the array) looks fine, however, I'd prefer a list instead of an array:

```
List<IUIElement> qwe = new List<IUIElement>();
qwe.Add(new UIElementButton());
qwe.Add(new UIElementLabel());
qwe.Add(new UIElementSomethingElse());

// some sample usages
foreach(IUIElement element in qwe)
{
   element.Click();
}

qwe[0].Click() //invokes UIElementButton.Click();

//gets all pointed elements
var pointedElements = qwe.Where(e => e.IsPointed(x,y));
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It really helped. Also no, I'm not from c++ background, I mostly do web programming in php where such problems as that don't arise, because you can put anything into an array regardles of datatypes, which is the reason for my confusion now...
Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: +1 for example uses. @NewProger c# is strongly typed meaning you're going to have to learn a slightly different paradigm to handle abstractions and inheritance hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question that this is the problem, but your code won't compile. In C#, you can't have `abstract` constructor. And the finalizer can't be neither `public` nor `abstract`. There is no need to have either of them, you can simply remove them.

And you probably shouldn't use the finalizer in general, unless you want dispose of some unmanaged resource. And if you need to that, you most likely want to implement `IDisposable` too.